# How to use IAM role with AWS Java SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-iam

My **use case is as follows:**

I **need to push some data into AWS SQS queue using JAVA SDK and by help of IAM role** (not using credential provider implementation).

**Is there any way to do that?**

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use role based authentication only on EC2 Instances, ECS Containers and Lambda functions. It is not possible to use them locally or on on premise servers.

[DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html) will automatically pick the EC2 Instance Role if it can't find the credentials via any of other methods. You can also create a custom [AWSCredentialsProviderChain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProviderChain.html) object with only injecting a instance of [InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.html) to it like here

```
AWSCredentialsProviderChain myCustomChain = new AWSCredentialsProviderChain(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider());
```

For more info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/java-sdk/latest/developer-guide/java-dg-roles.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply! IAM roles can also be associated on in ECS level (task/container). Not sure why you are saying that its limitation is only on EC2 level.

Comment: Sorry, I know it's a new functionality and that's why I just forgot. Lambda functions also can use roles.

Answer (score 11):

It's been a while, but this is not currently the case, it is now possible to use assume role with the Java SDK with a user. You can configure credentials in your `.aws/credentials` file as follows:

```
[useraccount]
aws_access_key_id=<key>
aws_secret_access_key=<secret>

[somerole]
role_arn=<the ARN of the role you want to assume>
source_profile=useraccount
```

Then, when you launch, set an environment variable: `AWS_PROFILE=somerole`

The SDK will use the credentials defined in `useraccount` to call `assumeRole` with the `role_arn` you provided. You'll of course need to be sure that the user with those credentials has the permissions to assume that role.

Note that if you're not including the full Java SDK in your project (i.e. you're including just the libraries for the services you need), you also need to include the `aws-java-sdk-sts` library in your classpath for this to work.

It is also possible to do all of this programmatically using `STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider`, but this would require you to directly configure all of the services so it might not be as convenient as the profile approach which should just work for all services.

Comment: question is regarding not to use credentials  but in your answer you indirectly using credential only, right?

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me out. Btw, the aws-java-sdk-sts" in gradle is the artifact `software.amazon.awssdk:sts:VERSION` (confirmed it works with version = `2.5.29`)

Comment: Gradle has nothign to do with it. I think what you meant is: The Artifact to use when using the AWS SDK for Java 2.x is `software.amazon.awssdk:sts` vs `com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sts` for of the AWS SDK for Java 1.x